# Wordpress wpdb not inserting/updating with HTML data

Tags: html, mysql, database, wordpress

So simply put, I have my PHP code generating a bunch of HTML. I then want to update a database entry like so

```
$wpdb->update("wp_table",
                array( 'content' => $html ),
                array( 'id' => 1 ),
                array( '%s' ),
                array( '%d' )
);
```

This simply does not work. Nothing in the database changes.

To debug, I placed the exact same code right above with one minor change, and it **DOES WORK**:

```
$wpdb->update("wp_sn_cached_popular_display",
                array( 'content' => "hello" ),
                array( 'id' => 1 ),
                array( '%s' ),
                array( '%d' )
);
```

(I swapped out the `$html` for a direct string.)

I can't even begin to comprehend why, and I've played around with it a lot. I've even done this and it **DOES WORK** too:

```
$string = "hello";

$wpdb->update("wp_sn_cached_popular_display",
                array( 'content' => $string),
                array( 'id' => 1 ),
                array( '%s' ),
                array( '%d' )
);
```

It's just the one `$html` variable is causing this function to not run, or something?

Compiling the `$html` variable is a bunch of stuff like this:

```
$html .= '<li>';
$html .= '<div class="upcoming-left">';
$html .= '<time datetime="' . $date . '" class="icon">';
$html .= '<em>' . $date_day.'</em>';
$html .= '<strong>' . $date_month . '</strong>';
$html .= '<span>' . $date_num . '</span>';
$html .= '</time>';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '<div class="upcoming-right">';
$html .= '<span class="upcoming-title"><a href="' . $upcoming_link . '">' . $upcoming_title . '</a></span>';
$html .= '<span class="upcoming-desc">' . $upcoming_desc . '</span>';
$html .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '</li>';
//...
```

Any ideas why this is?

**Bonus fun time: This appears to work on my local xampp insall, not the live site.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue with table datatypes
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp
depending on what the table is set to it may not support the string length of your html variable or certain chars in it.

It looks like you concat your .html var multiple times. It's a pretty long string in the end. to test this try to save a very long manually entered string. try with special chars. look at the table structure. This is just some ideas and where my thoughts go.

Comment: thanks, seems reasonable, I am however using "TEXT" in both cases (test xampp database and live database) which, according to the link you provided "Holds a string with a maximum length of 65,535 bytes"

Comment: You may be getting a php error if your $html string wasn't declared as a string before trying to concatenate. Perhaps change $html .= '<li>'; to $html = '<li>';
keep .= on the rest of them. Or just declare it as an empty string up top. Maybe you already are. This is just an easy mistake to make.

Comment: you were right, it was the datatype, I didn't even consider "text" and the "65,535 bytes" it holds wasn't "long", but it isn't - but there is a LONGTEXT type and that did the trick